# Change default binary label in a dummy variable

Tags: r, dummy-data, dummy-variable

I use `model.matrix()` method in `R` to generate dummy variables as:

```
dd <- data.frame(a = gl(2,2))
model.matrix(~ a - 1,dd)
```

Instead of 0 and 1 output labels, what parameter we need to set in `model.matrix()` so that output labels are -1 and 1?

Comment: Please read section: "Why not code binary inputs as 0 and 1" at link http://www.faqs.org/faqs/ai-faq/neural-nets/part2/

Answer (score 0):

Although I did not get it properly, but I followed these steps

```
dd <- data.frame(a = gl(2,2))
temp <- model.matrix(~ a - 1,dd)
temp <- apply(temp, 2, function(x) ifelse(x == 0, -1, 1))
```